# Need advice of refactoring views.py

Tags: python, django

I setup simple CRUD in Django

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from intentions.models import User,Prayer,Intention
from intentions.forms import IntentionForm, DeleteIntentionForm


def index(request):
    intentions = Intention.objects.all();
    return render_to_response('intentions/templates/index.html', 
                                {'intentions': intentions},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request)  
                            )

def show(request, id):
    try:
        intention = Intention.objects.get(pk=id)
    except Intention.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('intentions/templates/404_show.html')
    return render_to_response('intentions/templates/show.html', 
                                {'intention': intention, 'delete_form': DeleteIntentionForm(instance=intention)},
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request)  
                              )

def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = IntentionForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            intention = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('intention-show', args=[intention.id])) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = IntentionForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('intentions/templates/form.html', 
                                {'form': form, 'form_url': reverse_lazy('intention-new')},
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request)  
                              )
def edit(request, id):
    intention = Intention.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = IntentionForm(request.POST, instance=intention) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...

            intention = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('intention-show', args=[intention.id])) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        intention = Intention.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = IntentionForm(instance=intention) # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('intentions/templates/form.html', 
                                {'form': form, 'form_url': reverse_lazy('intention-edit', args=[intention.id])},
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request)  
                             )


def delete(request, id):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            intention = Intention.objects.get(pk=id)
        except Intention.DoesNotExist:
            return render_to_response('intentions/templates/404_show.html')    
        intention.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/') 
    else:
        return render_to_response('intentions/templates/404_show.html')
```

I see some fragments for refactor, but I am newbie in Python and Django and I would like to get advices from more experienced users about refactoring this code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Using `render` shortcut function is more preferable than `render_to_response`. The difference is explained on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5154458/455833)

```
def index(request):
    intentions = Intention.objects.all();
    return render('intentions/templates/index.html', {'intentions': intentions})
```

2.Then django has another shortcut [`get_object_or_404`](http://django.me/get_object_or_404)

```
intention = get_object_or_404(Intention, pk=id)
```

It raises 404 Exception which is processed by middleware. You don't need to call custom `HttpRequest` for that.

3.Here lazy version `reverse_lazy` is redundant. Call `reverse` instead.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('intention-show', args=[intention.id])) # Redirect after POST
```

4.You also can look through [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/). Django offers for you some base class to handle forms. It may reduce your code.